# Abstract Algebra: U(n) groups and cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic, cyclic-groups

The problem is:

> For every integer $n$ greater than 2, prove that the group $U(n^2-1)$ is not cyclic.

I have proved this for $U(2^n)$ where $n>2$ by showing more than one element of order 2 exists, which is a contradiction to Eulers phi function, making it noncyclic. As I try to apply similar logic to this problem, I seem to get stuck. Any ideas on how to manipulate this?

Comment: What do you know about $U(ab)$ if $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime?

Comment: What is $U(n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$gcd(n,n^2-1) = 1 \quad $  since $n(n) + (-1)*(n^2-1) = 1$ so $n \in U(n)$

Recall a cyclic group can have at most 1 subgroup of order 2. Consider the orders of the elements $\pm1 $ and $\pm n$ What are the orders of $<-1>, <n>, <-n>$

Comment: thanks for your help! So here's what I'm thinking now: 

Using the fact that $n∈U(n)$, I can say $n^2=(n^2-1)+1$ which is congruent to $1mod(n^2-1)$, hence $|n|=2$.Similar arguments show the same for $-n, -1$. Now we've shown this contradicts Eulers phi function, showing that the group cannot be cyclic. Is this a valid argument?

Comment: The fundamental theorem of cyclic group says that for every divisor k of the order of the group there is exactly one subgroup of order k. If the order of the group is odd it has no order 2 subgroups, if it is even then it has exactly one. {1,n}, {1,-n} and {1,n} and {1,-1} are all order 2 subgroups. So you've shown it contradicts the fundamental theorem of cyclic groups.